# Where Does WooCommerce Set the post_type to "product"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

WooCommerce is a set of plugins and themes that, when installed into Wordpress, create an ecommerce system. This is a question about the programatic implementation of a WooCommerce feature in the core of Wordpress.  The [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) explicitly forbids WooCommerce questions, and the Wordpress forums seem oriented towards users, not core developers.  i.e. -- Stack Overflow seems like the best place to ask this question, but if there's a better place, please let me know.

Products in WooCommerce are actually Wordpress posts, with the `post_type` data set to 'product`.

When you load the `http:://woo.example.com/shop` page, and Wordpress performs its post lookup query, the `post_type` is already set to `product`.

```
#File: wp-includes/query.php
if ( !empty($q['post_type']) && 'any' != $q['post_type'] ) {
}
```

Where does the WooCommerce plugin (or theme?) set this `post_type`? I'd assume via an `action` or a `filter`, but my Wordpress code tracing skills aren't up to the task of finding this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WooCommerce `WC_Template_Loader` class is responsible for loading the shop (i.e. archive) template, after the query arguments have been set in [class-wc-query.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/d59e3cb5483a1df6fc20839c9b1f50e98f4074a0/includes/class-wc-query.php#L205) via the `pre_get_posts` hook.